# Return text from DOM element

Tags: javascript, dom

I've written an algorithm to return the whole text from the specific DOM element. Is there a more efficient way of getting the whole text from within the DOM element.

My implementation is as follows:

```
function printText(element, textArray)
{
   for (var i = 0; i < element.childNodes.length; i++)
   {
      var node = element.childNodes[i];

      if (node instanceof Text)
      {
         textArray.push(node.wholeText);
      }
      else if (node instanceof HTMLElement)
      {
         printText(node, textArray);
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use,

- `element.innerText` to get only the visible text from the element and all its children,
- and `element.textContent` to get visible and hidden text from the element and its children.

Answer (score 0):

If you were using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), you could just get the container's [`.text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) property.

```
$(element).text();
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, Yeah, I'm looking for Javascript algorithm